# Program testing - JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am at the beginning of learning JUnit. How can I write a simple unit test for my code below? I have no idea of how to approach this.

#### File Factorial.java

```
public class Factorial {

    int Factor(int n) {
        int result = 1;
        int i;

        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public interface myFunc {
    int func(int n);
}
```

#### File Main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int factorial(myFunc mf, int n) {
        return mf.func(n);
    }

    public static int fact() {
        Factorial f = new Factorial();

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inINT = scanner.nextInt();

        int outINT = factorial(f::Factor, inINT);
        System.out.println(outINT);
        return outINT;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        fact();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Test
    public void test() {
        int n = 5;
        Factorial example = new Factorial();
        int result = example.Factor(n);
        assertEquals(6,result);
    }

Comment: post that as part of the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use the ability of your IDE to get the construct. [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) support creating the boilerplate code for you.

- NetBeans (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html)
- IntelliJ IDEA (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html)
- JUnit essentials (https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html)